# Will be whether multi-threading support in mongodb ( without locking database)

Tags: mongodb

As I know when I'm writing in database, others proccess wait while first process not yet completed?
Is it true?
If it true, maybe you know will be whether multi-threading in mongo and when?
Thanks.

Comment: Can't fully understand your question, but there is a database level lock when you write to some collection. Refer to the [concurrency](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/faq/concurrency/) topic of mongodb manual. If you are using mongodb 2.6, this lock is improved, you'll get collection level lock. Still, read the [concurrency](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/) manual of 2.6

Comment: Generally you don't need to worry about the lock. It's handled by the mongod and lasts only a little time. However, if you are looking for transaction like operations, it doesn't work this way. Mind providing more information about your use case?

Comment: for example, in a database every minute added a new collection. at this time added to the collection documents (10 per second). Collections can be greater than 1000. i.e. the database will be added in a second document 10000. collection consists of "id" and "time_insert" If we leave aside the technical issues and focus on Mongo. Whether mongo will cope with this task?

Comment: This is OK. You don't need to do the client side lock. Database will handle it for your.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if this is what you concern, mongodb is thread safe. You don't need to handle multi-thread stuff in your client side. The database will apply database level lock (2.4 or earlier) or collection level lock (new in mongo 2.6). Regarding what kind of lock it is using, refer to the [MongoDB FAQ about concurrency](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/)

> Beginning with version 2.2, MongoDB implements locks on a per-database basis for most read and write operations. Some global operations, typically short lived operations involving multiple databases, still require a global “instance” wide lock. Before 2.2, there is only one “global” lock per mongod instance.

However, it's thread safe doesn't mean you don't need to worry about thread at all. You may find it useful to use [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)

```
db.collection.findAndModify({
    query: <document>,
    sort: <document>,
    remove: <boolean>,
    update: <document>,
    new: <boolean>,
    fields: <document>,
    upsert: <boolean>
});
```

sometimes as described here in the [Atomic Operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-data-for-atomic-operations/) topic.

**EDIT:** Since 3.0, MongoDB introduced `WiredTiger` storage engine, now we got document level lock (only when you use `WiredTiger`)